# Subclassing iOS Model Objects - Appropriate Design Pattern

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns

I fear this is a rather simple question, but after much googling I think I have overshot my intended result. I believe my question to be related to a design pattern, but alas I could be wrong.

My application calls an RESTful API and gets back what amounts to a list of model objects represented by an `NSDictionary`. Each of which I will call `NNEntity`. There are (conceptually) multiple different subtypes of NNEntity. All subtypes of `NNEntity` share the property of `entityID`, but each have their own unique properties as well. All instances of `NNEntity` have a method called `readFromDict:(NSDictionary *)d` that populates their respective properties. This method is enforced by a protocol that all `NNEntity` subtypes conform to. It looks like this:

```
//NNEntity.h

@interface NNEntity : NSObject <NNReadFromDictProtocol>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *entityID;

@end

//NNEntity.m

@implementation NNEntity

- (void)readFromDict:(NSDictionary *)d {
    //set common properties from values in d
    self.entityID = [d objectForKey:@"ID"];
}
@end

//NNSubEntity1.h

@interface NNSubEntity1 : NSEntity <NNReadFromDictProtocol>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *favoriteColor;

@end

//NNSubEntity1.m

@implementation NNSubEntity1

- (void)readFromDict:(NSDictionary *)d {
    [super readFromDict:d];
    //set unique properties from values in d
    self.favoriteColor = [d objectForKey:@"colorPreference]:
}
@end

//NNSubEntity2.h

@interface NNSubEntity2 : NSEntity <NNReadFromDictProtocol>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *middleName;

@end

//NNSubEntity2.m

@implementation NNSubEntity2

- (void)readFromDict:(NSDictionary *)d {
    [super readFromDict:d];
    //set unique properties from values in d
    self.middleName = [d objectForKey:@"middleName]:
}
@end
```

I have read various pieces on the use of a Factory or Builder Desing pattern for similar use cases but I am curious if that is necessary in this rather simple case. For example, does my current code end up creating both and instance of `NNEntity` and `NNSubEntity2` if I were to call something like this:

```
NNEntity *newEntity = [[NNSubEntity2 alloc] init];
//assume dict exists already and is properly keyed
[newEntity readFromDict:dict];
```

I assume not, but would `newEntity` have both the common property of `entityID` as well as the unique property of `middleName` set correctly? Also, much appreciated if you have thoughts on a better or more efficient design approach.

Comment: I don't usually see people asking about how to make good design. +1 to that. :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like exactly how you should be doing it.  You have a base class which read in the common attributes, and subclasses which read in their specific attributes.

> For example, does my current code end up creating both and instance of NNEntity and NNSubEntity2? `NNEntity *newEntity = [[NNSubEntity2 alloc] init];`

Nope. When you run this, you instantiate `NNSubEntity2` and store the result in a variable typed by it's superclass, which is totally valid.  This allows you to call any methods defined on the superclass, but the actual instance is still of the subclass.

> Would newEntity have both the common property of entityID as well as the unique property of middleName set correctly?

It sure would.  It inherits the instance variables, properties and methods in the superclass.

---

Rest assured, as far as I can tell this looks sound and is a pattern I've used before.

Comment: Thanks! One minor follow up. When I get the list (array) of dictionaries back from my API, each one has a `type` key. I was thinking of creating a (factory) method in the `NNEntity` class like so `+ (NNEntity *)initWithType:(NSString *)typeStringFromAPI`. This would figure out the type of subclass it shoudd create and return it. Does it make sense to have a factory method like this in `NNEntity` or should I create a different factory class to do this? Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: In the `NSEntity` superclass, you can make a map of types to classnames, and combine with `NSClassFromString()` to grab the right class to instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this.

```
// NNEntity.h
@interface NNEntity : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *entityId;
@end;

// NNEntity.m
@implementation NNEntity
@end;


// NNEntity+KVC.h
@interface NNEnity (KVC)
-(void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
@end

// NNEntity+KVC.m
@implementation NNEntity (KVC)
-(void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
   // Handle this as appropriate to your app.
   // A minimal implementation will throw an exception.
}
@end
```

And similarly for your various subclasses. You don't (necessarily) need the category on your subclasses.

Then, given `NSDictionary *dict` with your stuff in it:

```
NNEntity *entity = [[NNEntity alloc] init];
[entity setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
```

Violá! You're done. There are some criticisms of this method, but given a strong implementation of `setValue:forUndefinedKey:`, I think it's safe and incredibly flexible.

The secrets are in Apple's beautiful [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i) technology. Essentially, `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` iterates the keys the dict you give it, and for eachinvokes `setValue:forKey:` in its receiver. It looks something like this (though I'm sure Apple optimizes it under the hood):

```
-(void)setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
   NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
   for (NSString* key in keys) {
      [self setValue:[dictionary valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
   }
}
```

I also like this approach because a conversion to [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is simple; when you tell CoreData to 'render' your model, it simply overwrites your stubbed model classes, keeping your KVC Category intact. What is more, if your implementation of `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` is smooth, you can make model changes to your backend without crashing the app (this is a bit of a no-no, but it's not much different from your factory solution).

Of course, I have not addressed your need to selectively choose which class to instantiate. But that is a larger design issue that could be affected even by the design of your API and backend. So I defer.

Also, as you noted in your comment below, the property names must match up. This is a show-stopper for some developers, especially so if you cannot control both the backend and the client.

Give it a try. Feedback is welcome.

Comment: This is interesting and thank you for the response. I assume that the properties on my model objects will have to match the names of the keys I am getting from the API. If they don't, or there is a new one I am not expecting, it will have to be handled by the `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` method. I believe I will combine this approach with the above approach to determine subclass type and give it a go.

Comment: Yes, that it correct - they must match letter-for-letter. Which is a drawback. Extra, or misspelled, properties in your model classes will not be a problem, extra, or misspelled, properties in your API will be handled by `setValue:forUndefinedKey:`. Where they match you will succeed.

Comment: Thanks much for this approach. Have been using it for the past year with no issue. It works really, really well for my situation where I control both the API and the iOS client.